# Index of N'th largest value in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range of values that may contain duplicates.  It looks something like this:

```
    A B C D
  ----------
1  23 1 
2  12 2
3  23 3
4  36 4
5  19 5
```

I want to display the 3 largest values, but I want to display the corresponding value from B, not the value in A.  I can find the 3 largest values from A by using

```
=LARGE(A1:A5,1)   # returns 36, I need it to return 4
=LARGE(A1:A5,2)   # returns 23, I need it to return 1
=LARGE(A1:A5,3)   # returns 23, I need it to return 3
```

Is there any way to do this?  I considered something based off of the RANK function, but RANK returns the same rank for equal items, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `D2:D4` use your 3 `LARGE` formulas to get `36`, `23`, `23` and then in E2 use this "array formula" to get the corresponding values from B1:B5, while accounting for possible duplicates:

`=INDEX(B$1:B$5,SMALL(IF(A$1:A$5=D2,ROW(A$1:A$5)-ROW(A$1)+1),COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: I believe that you mean `B$1:B$5` rather than `B$1,B$5`.  Also, I'm going to say the same thing to you that I say to the newbies: “While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could explain *why* it does so.  We’re looking for comprehensive, high-quality answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right.”

Comment: This works well.  I've only just recently learned about array formulas so I still have a hard time wrapping my head around constructing my own.  What happens when the IF() condition is false?  Wouldn't the formula result in an error?

Comment: @Scott, Yes, thanks that was a typo - correcting it now. I will also add some explanation....

Comment: @Zachary Turner. When the IF is FALSE the formula returns FALSE, so you get an array of numbers and FALSE values passed to the SMALL function. SMALL ignores logical values like TRUE and FALSE

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the use of a temporary column?  I need to do this for every cell of a large table, so making a temporary column for every cell is causing a bit of a problem.

Comment: To clarify, when I paste the LARGE() expression over the A$1:A$5 in your formula, I get a #NUM error.

Comment: I got it working on my own.  It was user error!

Comment: @ZacharyTurner, How did you do without the use of helper/temporary column? would you please share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

What about using a filter? You can sort Largest to smallest (correspondence between A and B elements is maintained) and then easily read the vaules from the first three cells in column B

Comment: Welcome on _SuperUser_. Meanwhile the algorithm can be an answer by itself often is likewise important for understanding to provide a line of code too...

Comment: I need to use the value in a computation, so I don't think a filter will work